# How can I rid my cal shaded animation render of this horrible artifacting?

Tags: rendering, animation, shaders, artifacts

When I render my character as a single image there are no issues at all, however the second it becomes a rendered animation the final pass is noisy and full of artifacts, is there any good way to clean it up? My render resolution is at 128px * 128px, using Eevee & using 256 samples. Thank you[image: noisy animation render]

[image: single image render]

Comment: What type of Animation Export do you use? Its likely, that is is compressed because its exported as Video

Comment: That was exactly the issue! I didn't consider that, thank you very much!